# Json.net output JSON contains "\" Characters?

Tags: json, json.net

Below is the output of the JSON from using Json.NET. Why are all of the "\" being inserted?

Output

```
{\"titles\":[{\"lesson\":1.0,\"title\":\"Objectives\"},{\"lesson\":2.0,\"title\":\"What are Cars?\"},{\"lesson\":3.0,\"title\":\"The Role of Cars\"}],\"objective\":[{\"objective\":\"Describe cars.\"},{\"objective\":\"Describe the role of cars.\"},{\"objective\":\"Define cars.\"}]}
```

Code

```
    Dim dst As DataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Dim writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)

    writer.WriteStartObject()

    If dst.Tables(1).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        writer.WritePropertyName("titles")
        writer.WriteStartArray()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer.WritePropertyName("lesson")
            writer.WriteValue(dst.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item("lesson"))
            writer.WritePropertyName("title")
            writer.WriteValue(dst.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item("title").ToString)

            writer.WriteEndObject()
        Next
        writer.WriteEndArray()
    End If

    If dst.Tables(2).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        writer.WritePropertyName("objective")
        writer.WriteStartArray()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer.WritePropertyName("objective")
            writer.WriteValue(dst.Tables(2).Rows(i).Item("objective"))

            writer.WriteEndObject()
        Next
        writer.WriteEndArray()
    End If
    writer.WriteEndObject()
```

Comment: Are you looking at the output in the debugger, or is this the actual output?  The debugger inserts backslashes so that you can copy values back into code.  If this is the actual output, then you must be double-serializing your object, which could happen if you are using Web API or some other framework that normally handles serialization for you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting all the "\" characters is because you just have a string.  That string needs to be parse like this

`JObject root = JObject.Parse('your_string_here');`

I hope that this helps you.